# C# How to Position a Parent Form using Client Coordinates?

Tags: c#, forms, winapi, properties, coordinate-systems

I have a main form (application's parent form) which is set to the back using p/Invoke `SetWindowPos`. `SetWindowPos` asks for the X,Y coordinates of the window which are to be in *Client Coordinates*.

When I start the program the window is displayed center of screen. I then move the window and save the new location to `Properties.Settings.Default.frmMainLocation` which is bound to the `frmMain.Location` property.

I stop the program and then restart it - and the form is back to the original center position.

**How would I set SetWindowPos to locate the window at X, Y Coordinates which are derived from the form's `Location.X`, `Location.Y` coordinates?**

Comment: Did you remember to include `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using p/invoke to set a form location?

Comment: I have saved the properties yes @RonBeyer I am not - I am using P/Invoke SetWindowPos to set it's Z order.

Comment: If you are only using SetWindowPos() to change the Z-order then you should be passing SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE as the last argument.  So it doesn't matter what you pass for the x, y, cx, cy arguments.

Comment: @HansPassant This is true but that does not mean I can not set the window position and have SetWindowPos position the window where I state!

Comment: @DaveGordon can you explain that comment to Hans? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `SetWindowPos()` will, by default, read the `x`, `y`, `cx`, and `cy` parameters and move your window there; you have to use the named flags to avoid this behavior.

Comment: @andlabs I unset the SWP_NOMOVE when moving the form and reset it afterwards ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a bit of a mess getting it to work.

When the App starts you need to `SetWindowPos` without the `SWP_NOMOVE` flag
Then `SetWindowPos` with the `SWP_MOVE` Flag set
Then when you want to change the position repeat the App start process.

Answer (score 1):

If you take your properties and save them to a point, you can set the window location like this:

```
Point pos = new Point
    (
        Properties.Settings.Default.posX,
        Properties.Settings.Default.posY
    );

this.Location = pos;
```

I set this in my form's `Form_Load()` method for the `Form.Load()` event with a few different sets of simple coords and it changed the position that the form was displayed on load each time. It's just a hop, skip, and a jump to have it load the coords from `Properties.Settings.Default` as I've shown in the example.